# Edit Google Contacts using google api php client

Tags: php, api, google-contacts-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to set up a Google Contact Sync feature using the google-api-php-client library.
I've been able to connect, retrieve and create contacts in my Google Contacts List using this php api library. But I can't seem to find a way to edit existing contacts.
The Official [Google Contacts API V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#Updating) Documentation says:

> To update a contact, first retrieve the contact entry, modify the data and send an authorized **PUT** request to the contact's edit URL with the modified contact entry in the body.

This is the code I've used so far.

```
    require_once '../includes/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Apps PHP Starter Application");
    $client->setScopes(array(
    'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/',
    'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/',
    'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
    'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/user/',
    ));
    $client->setClientId('[MY-CLIENT-ID]');
    $client->setClientSecret('[MY-CLIENT-SECRET]');
    $client->setRedirectUri('MY-REDIRECT-URI');
    $client->setAccessType('offline'); 
    $client->setDeveloperKey('DEVELOPER_KEY');
<h3>Google Authentication</h3>   
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
    {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
<h3>Refresh Token - To be used for later use</h3>
    $json_response= $_SESSION['token'];
    $decode_json = json_decode($json_response,true);
    $refreshtoken = $decode_json['refresh_token'];

    $qry = "UPDATE access_token set refresh_token='$refreshtoken', email='$email' where name = '$name'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $qry);
    }
    $qry = "Select * from access_token where name = '$name'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0 && !empty($row['refresh_token']))
    {
           $rtoken = $row['refresh_token'];
           $client->refreshToken($rtoken);
           $json_response= $client->getAccessToken();
           $_SESSION['token'] = $json_response;
           $_SESSION['rtoken'] = $rtoken;
<h3>Get Email of our Logged In User</h3>


    $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
    $req->setRequestHeaders(array('GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));
    $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);      
    $response =$val->getResponseBody(); // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); // Convert to an ARRAY
    $user_email = urlencode($xml->id); // email address
    unset($xml); // clean-up

<h3>Create a Contact</h3>

    $contact="
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>
    <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
    <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>HELLO</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>WORLD</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>Hello Changed Me</gd:fullName>
    </gd:name>
    <atom:content type='text'>Notes</atom:content>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
    primary='true' address='liz@gmail.com' displayName='E. Bennet'/>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home' address='liz@example.org'/>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'primary='true'>
    (206)555-1212
    </gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'>
    (206)555-1213
    </gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:im address='liz@gmail.com' protocol='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#GOOGLE_TALK'
    primary='true' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'/>
    <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work' primary='true'>
    <gd:city>Mountain View</gd:city>
    <gd:street>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</gd:street>
    <gd:region>CA</gd:region>
    <gd:postcode>94043</gd:postcode>
    <gd:country>United States</gd:country>
    <gd:formattedAddress>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View</gd:formattedAddress>
    </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
    <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false'
    href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/".$user_email."/base/6' />
    </atom:entry>
    ";

    $len = strlen($contact);
    $add = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/".$user_email."/full/");
    $add->setRequestMethod("POST");
    $add->setPostBody($contact);
    $add->setRequestHeaders(array('content-length' => $len, 'GData-Version'=> '3.0','content-type'=>'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));

    $submit = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($add);
    $sub_response = $submit->getResponseBody();

    $parsed = simplexml_load_string($sub_response); 
    $client_id = explode("base/",$parsed->id);
    var_dump($client_id);

<h3>Groups and Contacts Retrieval</h3>

    $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full?v=3");
            $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

            $xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

            $data['contacts'] = '<table class="table table-striped"><tbody>
            ';

            $output_array = array();

            foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
            {
                $output_array[] = array((string)$entry->title, (string)$entry->id);

                if((string)$entry->title == "")
                {
                    $name = "No name";
                }
                else
                {
                    $name = (string)$entry->title;
                    $name = str_replace("System Group:","", $name);
                }

                $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000&updated-min=2007-03-16T00:00:00&group=".(string)$entry->id."");
                $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

                $corrected_id = (string)$entry->id;
                $corrected_id = substr($corrected_id, strrpos($corrected_id, '/' )+1);

                $xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

                $output_array_2 = array();

                if(empty($xml->entry))
                {
                    $data['contacts'] .= '';
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['contacts'] .= '
            <tr class="success">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checker_'.$corrected_id.' inline" /></td>
                <td colspan="3">'.$name.'</td>
            </tr>
                    ';
                }

                foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
                {
                    foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email)
                    {
                        $output_array_2[] = array((string)$entry->title, (string)$email->attributes()->address);

                        if((string)$entry->title == "")
                        {
                            $name = "--- No Name ---";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $name = (string)$entry->title;
                        }

                        $data['contacts'] .= '
            <tr>
                <td style="width:10px;"><input type="checkbox" class="check_'.$corrected_id.'" name="email[]" value="'.(string)$email->attributes()->address.'" />'.$entry->id.'</td>
                <td>'.$name.'</td>
                <td>'.(string)$email->attributes()->address.'</td>
            </tr>';
                    }
                }
            }

    $data['contacts'] .= '
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    echo $data['contacts'];
    }
```

As you can see, I'm able to retrieve the contact entry, the problem remains; how do I send that entry back to the Google Contacts with the updated contact entry?
Please help me find a way.

Thanks,
Rizwan

Comment: Can you post some code im having trouble find where the Google php client lib supports contacts API.

Answer (score -1):

Check `Google_Http_Request` class. By using "PUT" in the `$method` parameter of the constructor, you will be able to send the information of the contact, as documented by Google.